# VoIP/SIP Soft Phone C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, voip, sip

I need to write VoIP/SIP Soft Phone in C# using WPF interface with Audio support only.
I need to have call transfer, call conference, and recording of conversations in mp3.

I've looked at VoIP SDK from ABTO LLC, but it is slow at application startup (30 seconds to start application, I think it's related to loading activex part of this sdk).

I've also looked at SIP.Net, but it's only for SIP and doesn't contain components for voice data transfer.

I have very limited time only 2 months from zero to fully working app.

What SDK can I use to accomplish this task?

Windows 7 must be supported.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# SIP Stack/Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498056/c-sip-stack-library)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have done this using **SipekSDK**. It's written on top of famous pjSIP open source SIPClient project. It does all the operations you have mentioned in the question.

https://sites.google.com/site/sipekvoip/

[image]

Comment: does it work on Windows 7? I've downloaded the softphone but it reports that it can't initialize Audio Mixer, i've traced down the problem to WaveLibMixer.dll and from what i see it's not supported on Vista and Windows 7

Comment: Yes it does support Windows 7 and vista platform. We have a softphone built using sipekSDK which successfully runs on both the platforms.

Comment: It's strange but i've tested few VOIP SDK's, and some of them including SipekSDK didn't found my sound and recording devices

Comment: I know it's an old thread, but for what it's worth. I couldn't find audio recording in this software. I am using NAudio for that part.

Answer (score 2):

What is the Sip server you are going to use ? If its not asterisk, you can have a look of **microsoft's Lync** [here](http://lync.microsoft.com/en-in/Overview/Pages/what-is-lync.aspx). 
You can download the [Lync SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d98f0bf7-c82c-47f5-9f73-be3edbf30438) and start exploring. Not just the audio call, Microsoft Lync has features like video call, chat, presence, conference etc.... and ofcourse connectivity to landline/pstn through voip providers

Another interesting article explaining the different SDKs for **unified communications** can be found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076536/what-are-difference-between-lync-server-2010-sdk-ucma-3-0-sdk-and-ucc-api)**

**Edit:** If its for Asterisk, Sipek is the only available free opensource but we had lot of problems in installing in clients system like

1. C folder access
2. Poor device
   support
3. Port conflict- If any
   other voip app like qutecom runs on
   5060, then Sipek wont run as the
   port is being used already.

Comment: I'm limited to APEX Sip Proxy so i can't use Lync, also i'm not sure about details of how i'm going to interact with it

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this exact issue and eventually came across ABTO LLC.
They have an SDK available that supports Win 7, Win XP and can be used in WPF.

We did ask them though to build a separate SDK example for us as we are using ClickOnce for our deployments and so registering external libraries is impossible, but they graciously did it and i think have integrated into their SDK, if not then ask them to give it to you.

We are using a FreeSwitch SIP Server combined with ABTO's library and it is working like a dream. We are doing VoIP, Video and Conferencing and have had no issues at all.

The application I added the VoIP functionality to is a WPF 4 app.